# Converting Plain Text with HTML/Markdown Hyperlinks to Rich Text Format in React for Pasting into Email Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, clipboard, rtf

I'm working on a React component named FlexButton that's designed to copy text from a textarea to the clipboard. When clicked, this button should copy text, potentially containing HTML hyperlinks, and allow it to be pasted into an email editor (in a customer support platform called Gladly) with hyperlinks intact.

Here's the current implementation for copying text to the clipboard:

```
 try {
     const textArea = document.querySelector("textarea");
    
     if (textArea) {
         await navigator.clipboard.writeText(textArea.textContent);
         setIsCopy(true);
         setTimeout(() => setIsCopy(false), 1500);
     }
} catch (e) {
     console.warn(e);
}
```

**The Challenge:**

The copied text may include HTML or markdown hyperlinks (e.g., `<a href="...">link</a>`, `[text](url)`) in plain text format. My goal is to ensure that when this text is pasted into the Gladly email editor, the hyperlinks are active and clickable.

**Attempted Solution:**

I tried converting the HTML content to Rich Text Format (RTF) before copying it to the clipboard. However, this approach results in the RTF code being pasted as plain text, not as formatted text with active hyperlinks.

**Questions:**

1. How can I modify my current implementation to copy text with HTML hyperlinks as active links when pasted into the email editor?
2. Are there any libraries or techniques in React or JavaScript that would facilitate this conversion?
3. Is it possible to interact with the clipboard in a way that preserves the hyperlink formatting?

Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this functionality would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem where using a text area for copying HTML content resulted in the loss of HTML formatting, as the text area only handles plain text. To resolve this, I developed a solution that involves rendering the same text from the textarea as HTML paragraphs (with `display: none`) and then programmatically selecting and copying them as HTML to the clipboard. This approach eliminates the need to convert the content to RTF.

This solution was inspired by a similar approach I found on Stack Overflow (unfortunately, I've lost the link to the original question). Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syoc803b/24/) example for reference.